# Reading back text data added to PNG image

Tags: delphi, png

In my Delphi app I create a PNG file which also includes some text as key-value pairs:

```
procedure TFrmMain.SaveasPNG1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Png: TPngImage;
begin
  if SaveDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    Png := TPngImage.Create;
    try
      Png.Assign(Image1.Picture.Graphic);
      Png.AddtEXt('SomeKey', 'SomeValue'); // <-- adding text
      Png.SaveToFile(SaveDialog1.FileName);
    finally
      Png.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I can't seem to find any [TPNGimage method](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.Imaging.pngimage.TPngImage_Methods) to read the data back, however. Is there a way to read the data back **in my app**?

(I'm using Delphi 11 Alexandria)

Comment: What you are adding is metadata. It can be viewed with any tool that can extract EXIF data. You can also right click the imaga in windows and select Details. You should see it there.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Eirik, but I tried to make clear that I want to read the data back in my app. Also TPNGImage doesn't seem to support EXIF at all; no writing, no reading.

Comment: Use the Header property to access the header object of the png image. The header object returned by this property contains useful information necessary for manipulating the png image metadata. 
Use the GetHeader to get the header information

From the documentation I assume you have read.

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Imaging.pngimage.TPngImage

Comment: Yes, I read the documentation, and didn't find anything about reading back the metadata, hence my question. Also: "Both the GetHeader method and Header property are internal and should not be used by applications directly. ", which is probably the reason any further documentation is lacking.

Comment: @EirikA. Both your comments are misleading: [PNG's metadata chunks](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html) have nothing to do with [Exif](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/exif). And `.GetHeader()` most likely only retrieves the `IHDR` chunk, which has no metadata either. Also in the future please use quotation marks when quoting text that is not yours. If you only make assumptions instead of actually knowing something then at least write so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `Png.AddtEXt()` a new data chunk of type `TChunkTEXT` is created and your data assigned to it.

You can retrieve such data back from the PNG by finding this data chunk using the `Png.Chunks.FindChunk()` method where you pass the `TChunkTEXT` class as parameter to the mentioned method. The code for retrieving such data would look like this:

```
var 
  TextChunk: TChunkTEXT;
  SomeKey, SomeValue: String;
begin
  ...
  TextChunk := TChunkTEXT(Png.Chunks.FindChunk(TChunkTEXT));
  SomeKey := TextChunk.Keyword;
  SomeValue := TextChunk.Text;
```

The only problem of the `.FindChunk()` method is that it only finds the first chunk matching the specified class - therefore you can retrieve only the first key-value pair even although it is possible to save multiple key-value pairs by calling `Png.AddtEXt()` multiple times.

In order to retrieve multiple key-value pairs from a PNG you will have to iterate through all chunks manually and retrieve data from text chunks. The code should look like this:

```
for I := 0 to Png.Chunks.Count-1 do
begin
  if Png.Chunks.Item[I] is TChunkTEXT then
  begin
    TextChunk := TChunkTEXT(Png.Chunks.Item[I]);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(TextChunk.Keyword + '=' + TextChunk.Text);
  end;
end;
```

PS: Yes the documentation on `TPNGimage` is a bit lacking but you can find how it works by peaking into the `Vcl.Imaging.pngimage` unit that ships with Delphi.

Comment: It's always `.AddtEXt()`, never `.AddEXt()`. The [PNG chunk's identification is `tEXt`](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html#C.tEXt).